# Where are the important locations in Minecraft Demo (1.16.4)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft Demo Mode (Since I don't have enough money for real minecraft) and I was attempting to complete the whole thing in the 100 minutes they give you. I was able to find a lava pool and build my own nether portal, but I couldn't find a nether fortress anywhere. I was wondering if someone could tell me the coordinates of a nether fortress in Demo Mode or at least tell me the location of the End Portal for me to be able to complete the game.

I believe the seed in Minecraft Demo is -343522682

Comment: For those of us who are trying to test out the seed, there is a sea chest at (169, 57, 185) and a lava pool at (139, 67, 284).

Comment: [Any%Glitchless(Demo) speedrun at Speedrun.com](https://www.speedrun.com/mc#Any_Glitchless_Demo) there's a run for 1.16 and runs in the 1.9-1.15 category.

Comment: @SF. I know there are runs for that category but what I need is exact coords they don't give any coords at all.

Comment: Just play a bit of the video, pause, follow in game, write down coords, You start in the same spot, and there are no cuts/skips in the video, so you should be able to reproduce all the locations just following visual cues.

Comment: @SF. I watched the videos and it seems that was run on a different version of minecraft since the seed generation may have changed.

Comment: The seed given is the same as the one you posted, and the run was on 1.16.1; the only worldgen difference between 1.16.1 and 1.16.4 is piglin brutes generated in bastions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming through here. I found the key locations for this seed on [Chunkbase](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/seed-map). They had all that I needed to complete the game.

If anyone needs to know a general run down of locations for the demo seed. Here they are.

There's a sea chest at (169, 57, 185). With a lava pool nearby for you to make your portal at (139, 67, 284).

Once you enter the Nether the closest nether fortress is at (91, ??, -325).

And the closest stronghold is at (-1852, ??, 1268). The portal room is at (-1823, 23, 1241).

Comment: Why did this get so popular?

Answer (score -2):

The main locations in Minecraft are nether Fortresses, a mine, I prefer to find a ravine since a lot of ores are exposed, a lava pool, and a water pool, and of course the end, you will need diamond gear to fight the ender dragon, and to get into the end you have to find the stronghold, but before that you have to find enderpearls, you can sometimes find some in the stronghold but never enough to fill the portal so you will have to go out and kill some endermen which can be found more often in the nether and they, have a high percentage about %89 chance of dropping ender pearls, then you need to kill blaze's, which are in the end and spawn on nether fortresses, they have  a %76 percent chance of dropping blaze rods which is what you'll need, once you have them put them in your crafting UI in your inventory in one corner which will make blaze powder, then combine the blaze powder and the enderpearls in 2 corners in your inventory and you will get eyes of ender then go back to the overworld and right click with the eye of ender and keep following it once it goes at an angle straight towards the ground then dig where it landed and keep digging and when you see mossy stone bricks dig through them and you'll be in the stronghold then place your eyes of ender on the end portal frame and then jump in, fight the ender dragon and...., you've beat the game! this is the important locations and how to beat the game in Minecraft Java Edition, and Minecraft Java Edition Demo, They are both the same except in the demo you don't have all privileges as in the original, such as commands, creative, multiplayer, etc.

Comment: Although its a good guide for beating Minecraft, I was wondering about location of important places like the nether fortress and the end portal for the demo seed, since it's the seed that people use frequently.